# Java generics type parameter hiding

Tags: java, generics, warnings

I'm defining a class:

```
class Foo<I extends Bar & Comparable<I>> {
}
```

the compiler is complaining about `I` being hidden by `I`. I guess the second time `I` appears in the definition is hiding in scope the first one, as if variable `I` could be assigned to two different types. How to do it correctly?

Edit:

this is an inner class. the full code can be:

```
class Baz<I> {
    class Foo<I extends Bar & Comparable<I>> {
    }
}
```

now the problem is that if I re-nominate inner `I` to `J`, i'm not sure that `I` and `J` are actually the same types.

Comment: Compiles for me - is there a type `I` defined elsewhere in your code?

Comment: Same, no warning for me.

Comment: yes, you're actually right. this is an inner class where the outer class is also using I. If I re-nominate `I` in `J` then i don't have the guarantee they are the same. Or?

Comment: The second `I` is the first `I`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't make the inner class parameterized:

```
class Baz<I extends Bar & Comparable<I>> {
   class Foo {
   }
}
```

As an inner (non-static nested) class, `I` as defined in the `Baz` declaration will still have meaning in `Foo`, since every `Foo` will have an implicit reference to its outer `Baz` instance.

Comment: i'll accept this as this answers my question. it might look like a banal question but my problem was different and I discovered it later. My problem was that the inner class was actually an inner interface. Can't avoid explicitly stating types in the inner interface, and that messed everything up for the inner classes implementing the inner interfaces...

Answer (score 3):

If `I` is already defined in the outer class just make this

```
public class Outer<I extends Bar & Comparable<I>> {
  public class Foo<I> {
  } 
}
```

You **cannot redefine `I`** in your inner class. The `I` of the inner class would be something else than the `I` of the outer class, if this is what you want, well, rename it.

HTH